# How to send a value to Controller from View using AJAX or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My code:
View:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function () {

//It was $("#uname").on("blur", function () { before edit

    var choiceId = $('#uname').val();
    var JSobj = {
        uname:choiceId
    };
    console.log(JSobj.uname + " Null");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/CheckUserName',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(JSobj),
            type: "post",
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
            var str = JSON.stringify(response);
            console.log(str);
            if (str == "true") {
                $("#usermsg").val("You are good to go");
                $("#usermsg").attr("color", "green");
            }
            else
                alert("Failure");
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("You should give up coding");
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div>

        @using(Html.BeginForm("Registration","Home"))
        {
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.UserName);
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.UserName, new { @id = "uname" });
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @id="usermsg" }) <br/>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.UserPassword);
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model=>Model.UserPassword);
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.UserPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) <br/>
        <div id="registration">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model=>Model.UserData.Fname);
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.UserData.Fname);

               <!--Added button here-->

                <input type="button" id="btn" value="Send" />

            </div>

        }
```

And my Controller:

```c#
//[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CheckUserName(string uname)
{
    bool flag;
    string name = uname;
    using (var context = new LoginEntities1())
    {
        LoginDetail detail = new LoginDetail();
        try
        {
            //var data = context.LoginDetails.ToList().Where(m => m.UserName == uname);
            flag = false;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
        return Json(flag);
}
```

I have tried every permutation and combination to send the value of `#uname` to the controller and yet it comes out to be null in the controller.
The Console does print out the value of `#uname` but however it is not passed onto the controller. Can anyone help me with this?

EDIT:

I obeserved a peculiar behavior. After I added an on click event on a submit button, in place of on blur. The controller is still being invoked on the on blur event, even if I don't click on the button.

Comment: What is any errors are you getting in the browser console? (and note you do not need the `contentType: 'application/json',` option - it can be just `data: JSobj,`)

Comment: In any case, it looks like you should be using the `[Remote]` attribute for this - [How to: Implement Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just want learn AJAX and that's why I'm doing this. Zero errors on the console.It just prints the username(input)+ Null, as expected. Thanks.

Comment: how is look like for the console.log?

Comment: When I enter "John" as the User Name it shows "John NULL." In 
the controller however it says, Null pointer exception to the uname variable. @Se0ng11

Comment: data: "{'uname':'"+ choiceId +"'}",  what about this?

Comment: Still Null @Hrishi

Comment: hmm, still can't seem to find the issue, if stringfy, the data should be correct {"uname":"John"}, maybe check the browser console, in the network tab, check what is the value is being pass on, suspect is because of the blur, another test, instead of blur, put a fake button, on click fire the ajax and see if the result is is passing correctly

Comment: I obeserved a peculiar behavior. After I added an on click event on a submit button, in place of on blur. The controller is still being invoked on the on blur event, even if I don't click on the button. The value from network shows: Form Data: json:"John" and URL encoded as: json:%22John%22. @Se0ng11

Comment: you need to refresh the cache if you had remove the blur event, and also, don't use submit button, use the normal button type button to fire the ajax, once click, 1st observe the network tab on the url, after that check on the server side,  the data that observe in the network tab should be like this {"uname":"John"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
 $("#btn").on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/CheckUserName?uname='+$('#uname').val(),                  
            type: "post",
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
            var str = response;
            console.log(str);
            if (str == "true") {
                $("#usermsg").val("You are good to go");
                $("#usermsg").attr("color", "green");
            }
            else
                alert("Failure");
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("You should give up coding");
        }
    });
})
```